# What are the best ways to represent different sections of text in one banner?

Tags: typography, text

I am tasked with creating banners for individual lecture series. I need to display the topic of the talk, the name of the talk as well as the lecturer. Sometimes the date as well. It looks strange when I use one typeface for all of the text, even when I try to resize it. When attempting to use a different font for each item it looks a bit busy.

Whatever I try, it feels like a wash of text that blends into itself. None of the information feels distinct from each other and it feels like the viewer is getting bombarded with info.

Are there any good practices for this?

Here's my attempt

[image]

But it doesn't look quite right.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just offhand, all uppercase, without punctuation makes I.T. read like "it" which causes a major hiccup for the reader.

Comment: Would changing it to I.T. be a solution?

Comment: @Matt That's what he was suggesting...

Comment: I hate all caps headings, especially when they're that long

Comment: Yes. Beyond theory, I feel that's a design *problem* you need to address. Because an acronym is used in the title, you either need to include the punctuation, or *not* use all uppercase type for the title. My preference would be the latter. All uppercase type is difficult to read in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### One type family won't kill your design

Hierarchy can be communicated via numerous devices:
Size,
weight,
color,
position,
and surrounding elements
all contribute to perceived hierarchy.

A change in typeface just says "something changed" — it doesn't necessarily establish order.

In this sample the head and subhead are the same size (if you don't count minor correction for optical variance between bold and light). A shift in **weight** and **color** structures the info.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Overall I find remaining consistent with typefaces helpful, but vary the faces. Use different faces (bold, italic, black, etc.) to create visual separation in conjunction with size.

First I'd determine what the **imperative information** is. If there are several of these banners, all focusing on the same talk but varying in date and topic, then the topic and date become the most important information to convey.

These should be more prominent than the global information such as the global title and the doctor's name. Although if the doctor is well known in these circles, his name *may* be a huge pull as well. In which case I'd have to rethink.

Answer (score -1):

1. It depends on the given subject matter.
2. Different sections of text used in one banner seems clumsy.
3. No matter which text is used and the thing is text character describe the information.
4. And the best way to represent the texts in one banner is playing with them in clever manner, perhaps by changing the

   - Size of main text with their relative text character
   - Text color information
   - Smart use of text in white space..